# ModelState.IsValid = False

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

`ModelState` is throwing an error that one of the parameters `[UserId]` is `null`. That field isn't being set on my form. It's being set in the controller.

How do I remove it from the ModelState.IsValid test?

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,UserId,Created,TimeStamp,Name,Role,Description,Partner,PartnerAmount,Competitor,IsDeleted")] Relationship relationship)
    {
        relationship.UserId = User.Identity.Name.Replace(@"XXXXX\","");
        relationship.Created = DateTime.Now;
        relationship.TimeStamp = DateTime.Now;
        relationship.IsDeleted = false;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Add(relationship);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(relationship);
    }
```

It won't pass ModelState.IsValid b/c of UserId.  But, it doesn't check Created,  Timestamp or IsDeleted.  Why doesn't it check those, but it does check UserId?  All of these fields are required in my Model.

Comment: can you show the view pls?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the field from the view model. If you don't have one, create on. Using entities in your views generates security vurnabilities as an attacker could set fields that you might not change once posted.

Using an view model makes sure that only fields that are allowed to be changed are available in the browser.

If you still want to use your entity, change the UserId to `int?` which tells the model validator that it doesn't have to be set.

You can also remove the validations `ModelState["UserId"].Errors.Clear()`; But I strongly discourage from that. Use a specific view model.

Comment: I have other fields in my model that I'm setting in the controller and they're not appearing in the ModelState.IsValid test.  So why some fields in the model are tested, and others aren't?

Comment: Not nullable types must be specified according to the validator. That's why `int?` works for UserId

Comment: created and timestamp are both required, but they aren't in the ModelState.Isvalid test

Comment: created and timestam are not nullable,  so they have a default value already. This is why they are valid.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change ModelState.IsValid by changing any properties inside of the controller. IsValid still will be the same, since a list of errors will be the same. UserId should be assigned before the model reaches the controller.

So assign UserId=0 if it is nullable and  add this line somewhere inside of the form of the view,

```
<input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.UserId" value="@Model.UserId"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the controller action method, try to use [Rerun validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-5.0#rerun-validation), call the TryValidateModel method, as shown here:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,UserId,Created,TimeStamp,Name,Role,Description,Partner,PartnerAmount,Competitor,IsDeleted")] Relationship relationship)
{
    relationship.UserId = User.Identity.Name.Replace(@"XXXXX\","");
    relationship.Created = DateTime.Now;
    relationship.TimeStamp = DateTime.Now;
    relationship.IsDeleted = false;

    if (!TryValidateModel(relationship, nameof(relationship)))
    { 
        return View(relationship);
    }
    _context.Add(relationship);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
}
```